# how to import node module in html/javascript page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-modules

How to call my node module in HTML/Javascript page.

node.js page

```
exports.books = async (req, res) => {
const booksRef = db.collection('Books');
try{
        booksRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
        const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
    }));
        console.log(data);
        return res.status(201).json(data);
    })
} catch (error) {
    return res
    .status(500)
    .json({ general: "Something went wrong, please try again"});          
}
```

};

home.html page
how to import/call node module books in HTML/javascript function

```
<script type="module" src="./module.js"></script>
    
function funs_del(a)
    {   
        alert('start');
        **// call node module(books) here.......**
        alert('stop');
        
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here makes sense.  You won't (or, at least, _shouldn't_) be able to call your database directly from a webpage running in a browser.  Instead, you'd want to create API endpoints (REST being the most common) that provide limited and structured access to data, and call those endpoints from your webpage.  Providing direct database access from a web application is about as massive as a security hole can get.

Comment: Your server needs an endpoint that you can reach with `fetch(endpoint)`. The endpoint would trigger that function when called. It's not clear if you're using any backend framework to help you with this but [here's how Express does it](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html).